# Content Security Policy NOT work ONLY in Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, content-security-policy

I need to use CSP ( Content Security Policy ) in .htaccess in order to improve the security of my website. It works fine in all browser, but NOT in Firefox. By using the "console" tag in browsers inspection, there is not error or refused message, the whole website works fine.  But when I access the website with Firefix, the website does not load the features (, , , etc...) due to CSP code.  Refused messages are showing, but it ony happens in Firefox. I did a lot of search on internet, nothing helped me... Does anyone?

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'self'; connect-src 'self' cloudflareinsights.com; img-src 'self' i.ytimg.com; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' *.youtube.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' ajax.cloudflare.com static.cloudflareinsights.com; style-src 'self' 'nonce-scrline' *.googleapis.com 'sha256-OnKjgfO74jp5PdYX4b31P2gAs34UqQ1Nl3hDLfxVu1Y='; form-action 'self'; media-src 'self'"`

This is the CSP line's. P.S: there is no extension in Firefox... it is up to date! I purge cache in Cloudflare, i delete cache in Firefox, nothing happens. ALL BROWSERS works. What is wrong with this *&&*%&ˆ$% of Firefox?